# Does Microsoft Office 2010 have version control?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010, version-control

Does Microsoft Office 2010 have version control?  In other words, does it automatically save old versions of files?

Answer (score 14):

No. It has AutoRecover and Track Changes but not a versioning history.

You may be interested in using [P4OFC](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/products/plugins-ofc.html) if you need version control on Office documents.

> **Perforce Plug-in for Microsoft Office**
>
> P4OFC, the Perforce Plug-in for Microsoft Office, allows Microsoft Word, Excel,
> PowerPoint, and Project files to be easily stored and managed in Perforce. With P4OFC, users don't have to leave a familiar environment to bring their documents under Perforce control.
>
> *Support for Basic SCM Tasks*
>
> P4OFC helps everyday users to:
>
> - Check files in and out of Perforce from within Microsoft Word, Excel, PowerPoint and Project
> - Determine which version of a document is checked out and who else is working on it
> - Access complete document revision history
> - Share and lock documents through Perforce
> - Link change requests with document changes
>
> *Implement Document Management Quickly and Easily*
>
> P4OFC is easy to install and adds a "Perforce" menu to Microsoft Office applications. Once installed, the plug-in automatically determines which documents are under Perforce control.
>
> *Quickly Compare Two Versions of the Same Word Document*
>
> P4OFC can compare any two revisions of the same Word document and quickly show changes, using Microsoft Word's Track Changes feature.

A Perforce repository is free for two users.

Answer (score 9):

A Word file can contain multiple versions. Use menu *File* | *Info* | *Manage Versions*.

Otherwise, it is only possible using some external software (version control or [SharePoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint)).

Comment: I can't find a matching feature in more recent Word 14.2.4 (120824) so for compatibility, I should hesitate before using Microsoft's implementation of versions.

Comment: @GrahamPerrin In Word 2010 (V14.0) I've just double checked: versions is in the info page for the document. For 2013 it might have moved (I don't have 2013 installed anywhere yet) but I would be very surprised if the feature had been completely removed.

Comment: Thanks. In Ask Different Chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6752019#6752019

Comment: In Word 2013 ([version unknown](http://www.wuala.com/grahamperrin/public/2012/11/03/b/?mode=gallery)) there's the interface to manage versions, but unless I'm missing something: [no way to save (add) a version](http://www.wuala.com/grahamperrin/public/2012/11/03/c/?mode=gallery). Maybe the same is true of Office 2010. Incidentally the SharePoint service provided to me is not versions-enabled.

Answer (score 6):

Word used to have built=in Version Control.  But that was removed in Word 2007:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/what-happened-to-versioning-HA010219332.aspx

Now, they have 3 related features:

1. Track Changes.  This allows you to see any changes that have been made to a document and either approve or reject the changes.
2. Manage Versions.  This allows you to recover autosaved versions of a file.
3. Document Library.  If you save your documents on a Sharepoint server, you can view earlier versions.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/compare-versions-of-a-word-document-in-a-document-library-HA010202675.aspx?CTT=1

Answer (score 4):

Whilst the above answers are correct in general (Office 2010 does not support version control), there is one exception: Access 2010 has an option which you can enable for it ("Source Control" is a menu choice in the Options menu under the Ribbon settings section).

The information returned by a search of the internet is pretty limited, so I don't think it can have received a lot of attention from Access users in general.

The details on Microsoft's website are here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=6840

Answer (score 2):

We (disclaimer, I'm the founder) built a version control system for Excel (think GitHub for spreadsheets). Have a look: https://spreadgit.com

Comment: Strange coincidence to bump into you on here, but the demo you gave us the other day was really good! Would definitely recommend others take a look at it.

Comment: Ha, the world is a small place indeed. Thanks, Neil!